# Why do I have to import openpyxl in this code?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Why do you have to import openpyxl in this code? Aren't both of the lines of code here using pandas exclusively, or am I missing something?

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.DataFrame([11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23],[31, 32, 33], index = ['one', 'two', 'three'], columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.to_excel('new_excel', sheet_name='new_sheet_name')
```

Comment: Ignoring the errors in code creating the DataFrame, you don't need to  **import** openpyxl for the snippet to run. You need it installed though.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @buran, you **don't** need to **import** `openpyxl`, but you **do** need it **installed**. The reason being is because `to_excel` depends on either `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter` to write the excel file depending on the file extension. You can read more about it in the [`documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) for `to_excel`.

Comment: I though it was dependant on the engine, with the default being Openpyxl. Both openpyxl and xlsxwriter write the same file type, xlsx.

Comment: @moken, here is a direct quote from the documentation I linked in the answer: `To set the library that is used to write the Excel file, you can pass the engine keyword (the default engine is automatically chosen depending on the file extension)`